# "World War II" or "The World War II"?

Tags: articles

I just watched this video on YouTube [**5 Unexplained Mysteries Of World War II!**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2GmIm1w1BE) and was surprised that many viewers were almost enraged by the fact that the author said many times "the world war II" instead of just "world war II". Not being a native speaker of English, I was quite surprised and also ashamed because I say "the world war II" quite often. Now I understand that it's wrong to do so.

However, I still don't understand the reason. In the comments under that video, there was an argument brought up that "World war II" is a name - just like "Facebook" or "Tony" - and names are not to be used with "the". But I noticed that in Wikipedia, while the article on that war is titled as "World War II", another name for that war in the article is used with "the" quite often - "the second world war".

Also, I remember how Ed Sullivan [**was announcing the Beatles on his show**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=It3Cctk6BRs&t=2s): "Ladies and gentlemen, the Beatles" - he did use "the" then even though "Beatles" is a name.

So, why not "The World War II"? And why so many viewers were so angry? Does "The World war II" sound somewhat insulting to native English speakers?

Comment: The short answer is that you never use definite articles with names unless the article happened to be part of the name itself.

Comment: Sullivan introduced them as ["The Beatles"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles) because that's the name of the band.

Comment: Videos on Youtube are often made and commented upon by uneducated or non-native speakers. Also, the comments sections are notorious for the likelihood of rude, angry or stupid items. We would use the definite article for 'the Second World War". I have seen it alleged that most British people tend to use "the Second World War" when writing formally, and Americans "World War II.", but I do not have any scientific evidence.

Answer (score 1):

Because "Second World War" *isn't* originally a name, being, instead, a construction built by taking the term "world war" and adding a "second" in the front to differentiate it from the "*First* World War", it needs a "the" in front of it.  If it helps, you can mentally split it into "the second" + "world war", which should make this clearer.  "World War II", on the other hand, *is* a typical name, and, thus, needs no "the" in front of it.